# Closing WP_LINK_PAGES DIV ID w/After Argmuent

Tags: php, functions, wp-link-pages

In my code below I need to close the div "link_wrap" which I created with `$args['before'] = '<div id="link_wrap">';`

When I try to paste `$args['after'] = '</div>';` *above* `return $args;` it adds the appropriate closing div but also renders the rest of my code, which allows *both* previous/next links and pagination, completely useless.

How do I properly close the div while maintaining the functionality of the rest of my code?

```
// WP_LINK_PAGES: Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');

    function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    $args['before'] = '<div id="link_wrap">';
    $args['link_before'] = '<span class="classlinks">';
    $args['link_after'] = '</span>';

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= ' '. _wp_link_page($page-1) 
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['previouspagelink']  . '</a>' . ' '
        ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = ' '. _wp_link_page($page+1)
           . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink']  . '</a>'
        ;

    return $args;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare the after arg at the beginning of your code:

```
$args['before'] = '<div id="link_wrap">';    
$args['after']  = '</div>';
```

When there is a next page, the arg is overwritten, so you'll have to add the closing tag at the end:

```
if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
    $args['after'] = ' '. _wp_link_page($page+1)
       . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink']  . '</a></div>'
    ;
```